# How do I set a Canvas to a specific size in world units in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Assuming that I have a UI Canvas which is set to 'World Space' and positioned absolutely in the world above my cube.

My cube is resized at runtime.

Without *scaling* the canvas, how do I set the size of the canvas to match the known world unit width of my cube?

I know that you can set the canvas in 'canvas units' using:

```
var rect = canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(200, 200);
```

However, 200x200 are canvas units, not world units; my cube is 4 units wide; what should the `sizeDelta` be set to?

I presume this has something to do with the `CanvasScale` component, but I can't figure it out; `referenceUnitsPerPixel` is 100, and that's completely wrong as a scale factor, and `dynamicPixelsPerUnit` is like 1, which is wrong too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do it:

- set the **Canvas** component *Render Mode* property to *World* (you already did that)
- remove the **CanvasScaler** component
- your canvas is now a 3D object: set its size using **RectTransform** *Width* and *Height*

Just keep in mind your **Canvas** will not deal with very small size elements (default **Image** is 100x100 which will be much larger than your **Canvas**).

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: I don't really understand why this works (or more to the point, what the Canvas Scaler is actually doing that makes it not work when its present), but that totally works, thanks!

Comment: Well basically the **CanvasScaler** is here to automatically adapt your UI to multiple screens sizes/resolutions. I your situation (and most of the times when _RenderMode_ is set to _World_), it's not needed to scale it since you can adjust it in world units: exceptions may be for example the width of a 3D HUD if you want it to "fill" the whole screen on 4:3, 16:9 or 21:9 screens. Hope I was clear enough: otherwise I'll try to explain it further in my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

> If you want it to have a specific width in meters, you can can calculate the needed scale by using meter_size / canvas_width. For example, if you want it to be 2 meters wide and the Canvas width is 800, you would have 2 / 800 = 0.0025. You then set the Scale property of the Rect Transform on the Canvas to 0.0025 for both X, Y, and Z in order to ensure that it’s uniformly scaled.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIWorldSpace.html

Comment: Your answer ---> 'You then set the Scale property of the Rect Transform' ... my question ---> '**Without scaling** the canvas...'

Comment: I will keep it since its Unitys preferred way of setting the size of a in world canvas

Comment: If you want to leave the answer here, sure, but answering a question with a solution that was *specifically asked* not to be used in the question rightly deserves to be downvoted. This isn't a best practice discussion site; it's a Q/A site and you just flat out didn't read the question. Also, please *do not* deface the question.

Comment: Its a bad question you should tell WHY you dont want to scale it since thats the way you do it in unity. You are working against the SDK

Comment: Scaling the canvas distorts the content when the x/y scale is not equal, which obviously makes it *totally* unsuitable for dynamic resizing. (I might add that responsive resizing is the *reason* the rect transform has anchors; otherwise it would just be a fixed offset layout system)